# Will jQuery select hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I call `.hide()` on an element, will/can jQuery select it in a normal dom selector.

If jQuery does normally select hidden elements, what is the proper way to select only visible elements. Can I use a css selector, or is there a more valid way of doing this?

Comment: That's one of the advantages of separating structure from style.

Comment: I really don't understand why this question was closed as not constructive.  It seems to me that he's asking a very simple yes/no question, and then asking for a method to accomplish a very specific goal.  I don't understand why it would be likely to "solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."  I'm not necessarily disagreeing, but I'd just like to understand what criteria this question did not meet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The `hide` function only stores the current value of the display css property of your element, then set it to `none`. So the dom selectors will not be affected by it unless they try to match elements with a particular `display` css value.

Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MhKwm/).

Have a look at the [jQuery `hide` function documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will count hidden elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it just adds a display:none style to the element... .remove() on the other hand will not show up in counts. But that completely gets rid of it, and unless you store the value somewhere it is not retrievable.

What I'm assuming you want to do is to count the visible items. I would instead do the following:

```
$('.element').addClass('hide');

var count_of_visible_items = $('.element:not(".hide")').length;
console.log(count_of_visible_items);
```